# Puppeteer: iterate through URL's & wait to print in order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

So I'm trying to use puppeteer to iterate through some URL's, grab data from the HTML contents, and print out a CSV.

I'm stuck at the part where you print the data out.  Right now I'm just testing and trying to do a console.log() for each piece of data.

The main problem I'm having is that the loop runs very quickly, opens a ton of browser windows, and does the logs all out of order.

Here's my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async (i) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(`https://webPageURL.org/list/objects/${i}/`);
  await page.waitFor(1000);

  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let data = document.querySelector('.someClass')
    if (data !== null) {
      data = data.innerText;
    }
    return {
      data
    }
  });
  await browser.close();
  return result;
};
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++{
    scrape(i).then((value) => {
      console.log(i, ': ', value);
    });
  }
```

What I want is for the loop to pause until something prints, but what happens when I run this specific code is that ten browser windows open and load at once, and they all print to the console in whatever random order they resolve.  Also, ideally I want the scraper to pause from loading the next page until the current loop iteration is done printing.  This is because I will need to do this process for about 5000 pages and ideally I don't want to open 5000 browsers.

Comment: Your syntax is off. `if (data !== null) {
        data = data.innerText;
      );`

Comment: thank you!  i simplified this for SO and missed some deletions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to `await` each iteration, to ensure the `for` loop doesn't continue until the current call of `scrape` is finished. Luckily, `scrape` is an `async` function, so it returns a `Promise` already. Clean up all the syntax errors in your code (mismatched brackets and parentheses and such, if the code is simplified and working in its original form, this isn't relevant), and then:

```
(async () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    await scrape(i).then((value) => {
      console.log(i, ': ', value);
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what i needed.  I'm still.... inexperienced using async